# How to create JPA Query that returns an element and related element array

Tags: java, jpa

I have One to many association between elements RequestEntity and ResultEntity. One Request can have multiple results and I want to return them all without repeating RequestEntity every time, for now, I have this:

```
@Query("SELECT p, s FROM  RequestEntity p  left JOIN ResultEntity s on s.result = p.id where p.user = :user AND p.id = :id")
Object[] getRequestEntityByIdAndUser(@Param("id")  String Id, @Param("user")  String user);
```

This Query returns:

[ [ { RequestEntity1 } { ResultEntity1} ], [ { RequestEntity1 } { ResultEntity2} ], ... ]

Is there any way to make it return: without repeating the same data? for example:

[  { RequestEntity1 }, [ { ResultEntity1}, { ResultEntity2}, ...] ]

Comment: just tried it now, did not help, as far as I googled, select distinct - selects only one element from DB if there are duplicate values, which is not the problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

Not what I wanted, but works as intended. I just made 2 calls to database and merged them:

```
public Object[] getRequest(String user, String id) {
Set<ResultEntity> results = resultRepository.findResultEntityByResult(id);
    Object req = requestRepository.getRequestEntityByIdAndUser(id, user);
    Object[] obj = new Object[] { results, req};
return obj;
}
```